# Ruby on Rails NoMethodError only on first load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

The first time my application loads, I get an error.  If I immediately reload the page, the application loads fine.  That's not a big deal in development, but in production it seems to cache the error.  I've tried ruby 1.9.2-p136, 1.9.2-p180, 1.9.2-p290, but they all seem to do the same.  Below is the output from the DEVELOPMENT environment.  Further down is the log from nginx which yields a 502 Bad Gateway, seemingly caching the NoMethodError.

```
$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.5 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2011-09-16 19:13:39] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-09-16 19:13:39] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [i686-linux]
[2011-09-16 19:13:39] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2260 port=3000

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-09-16 19:13:42 -0400

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for false:FalseClass):

Rendered /home/paisley/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p290-fts/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (0.9ms)
Rendered /home/paisley/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p290-fts/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (6.2ms)
Rendered /home/paisley/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p290-fts/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (11.1ms)

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-09-16 19:13:44 -0400
  Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
Rendered welcome/index.haml within layouts/application (13.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 18ms (Views: 17.5ms)
```

nginx error log below:

```
2011/09/16 19:21:29 [error] 15002#0: *30 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 74.71.201.247, server: redacted.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/passenger_helper_server:", host: "redacted.com"
[ pid=19637 thr=74145680 file=utils.rb:176 time=2011-09-16 19:21:29.767 ]: *** Exception NoMethodError in application (undefined method `[]' for false:FalseClass) (process 19637, thread #<Thread:0x8d6bf20>):
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:59:in `establish_connection'
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55:in `establish_connection'
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1900:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:397:in `before_handling_requests'
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:204:in `start_request_handler'
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:170:in `block in handle_spawn_application'
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:479:in `safe_fork'
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:165:in `handle_spawn_application'
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:128:in `start'
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `block in spawn_rack_application'
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `block in synchronize'
    from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
    from /opt/tool/install/ruby-1.9.2-p180-tasks/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems that the error was caused by not using config/database.yml.  Once I filled that file out, it behaves even though the application doesn't use ActiveRecord or even have models.  I'll leave this out there to see if that helps anyone figure out what's *really* going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application doesn't use ActiveRecord, you should set your project up a little differently.

In your Gemfile, instead of add 'rails', just add these:

```
RAILS_VERSION = '~> 3.0'

gem 'activesupport',      RAILS_VERSION, :require => 'active_support'
gem 'actionpack',         RAILS_VERSION, :require => 'action_pack'
gem 'actionmailer',       RAILS_VERSION, :require => 'action_mailer'
gem 'railties',           RAILS_VERSION, :require => 'rails'
```

That's everything in Rails except ActiveRecord.

Now you also have to modify your config/application.rb, so instead of `require "rails"`, it just does:

```
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

If you're not using Test::Unit, remove that railtie from above excerpt.

Comment: With this solution, you don't even need to have a config/database.yml.  Perfect, thanks.